# Can I call a property from another object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I am using `FlatList` in React Native to show a list of products. I don't hold the quantity of products that I am adding; this quantity is held in another object in which I want to get by using the ID of the product object.

```js
 //Just added this 
    const productsAdded = useSelector(state => state.cart.items);
// productsAdded is an object that contains the items in my cart

<FlatList
    data={products}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={itemData => 
        <ProductItem
            image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
            title={itemData.item.title}
            price={itemData.item.price}
            units={itemData.item.units}
        >
        {pID = itemData.item.id,
        console.log("---------Testing PID------"),
        console.log(pID),    // pID here works fine!
        console.log(productsAdded.pID)  //pID here is not recognize as a value that I could pass to productsAdded which is the object from where I want to retrieve the quantity **       
        }
...
```

In short, I am getting the ID from the products object. How do I pass it as a property to `productsAdded`?

Comment: `<productsAdded id={pID} /> // id can be pID as well`

Comment: where do you init productsAdded variable?

Comment: Is productsAdded a class or a helper function? Is it fetching the ids asynronously or instant? That matters for a potential answer.

Comment: I just edit where I am declaring my productsAdded variable
This is an object that contains all the products in the cart ... I could definitely get productsAdded.id but the ID I want to get exactly is the one from the item rendered in the flatlist.